# Sort by age method, and list in class

Tags: java

I'm trying to refresh my java skills here. I am working on a simple java assignment. Below are the first two instructions.

1. Create an Employee class with following attributes / variables:
   name
   age
   department
2. Create a class called Department which will contain a list of employees.

a) Department class will have a method which will return its employees ordered by age.

b) The value of department can be only one of the following values:
        “Accounting”
        “Marketing”
        “Human Resources”
        “Information Systems”

I'm having a little trouble with step 2. I need help **figuring out how to add a list of employees like it says**, and ***how to write the method which will return by sorting the employees ordered by age***.
I would just like for someone to explain how to do this. Thanks.

So far I have this.

Employee Class:

```
 package simpleJavaAssignment;

public class Employee {
String name;
int age;
Department department;


Employee(String n, int a, Department d)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.age = a;
    this.department = d;
}
int gAge(){

return age;
}
}
```

Department Class:

```
package simpleJavaAssignment;
import java.util.*;

public enum Department {

   ACCOUNTING("Accounting"), MARKETING("Marketing"), HUMAN_RESOURCES(
        "Human Resources"), INFORMATION_SYSTEMS("Information Systems");

   private String deptName;

    Department(String deptName) {
       this.deptName = deptName;
    }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
    return this.deptName;
   }

}
```

Comment: As a design point, you probably shouldn't be using an `enum` for department types, as they can change relatively frequently.  Also, what you call `Department` is just the name of a department.  `Department` should be a class containing a collection of `Employee` objects.

Comment: make the Employee class implement the Comparator interface

Comment: As far (b) goes you just need to provide some validation in your setter for the `department` variable. Provide a static collection of allowed department strings and check against that when you set the `Employee`'s department. If it fails then re-prompt the user for an acceptable one. Also, I can't be sure but, it seems like having a `Department` instance in your `Employee` seems wrong. Why would you need the department which could potentially contain thousands of entries in an employees record. I think you need the inverse of that.

Comment: I'd also have to ponder if `Department` would not be a super class that the specific departments extend.

Answer (score 3):

You have the beginnings of a solution but you are a ways off yet.

Your `Department` class (should be a class and not an enum), should contain a collection of `Employee` objects.  There should also be a collection of departments at the top level in your program.

As to sorting, you should look at the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.  You implement a custom subclass of `Comparator` that allows the builtin collection sorting algorithms to compare Employee instances such that the desired order is achieved.

```
public class EmployeeAgeComparator implements Comparator<Employee>
{
    public int compare(Employee e) 
    {
        return (this.age < e.age)
            ? -1
            : (this.age > e.age) 
                 ? +1
                 : 0;
    }
}
```

This fulfills the `Comparator` contract by returning `-1` if this `Employee` is younger than `e`, zero if they are the same age, and `+1` if this `Employee` is older.

Comment: I would suggest that you implemement `Comparable` in the Employee class. Comparable is simpler and more natural - you think of it as defining a preferred default sort order for instances of Employee. `Comparator` is more flexible and general. You can plug in a Comparator to a specific collection to control the sort order you want right here and now.

Comment: In this case I suggest using a separate `Comparator` since there are probably going to be several different ways to sort Employees.  I might put the primary sorting option in the Employee object, but age would not be my choice for a primary sorting option.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the list of employees be ordered by age when you add an employee to the list.
Then when you want to get the list, you just return it.

You should not contain a `Department` member in `Employee` class, Conversely, `Department` class should contain a list of `Employee`.

```
package simpleJavaAssignment;
import java.util.*;

public class Department {
    private String deptName;
    private ArrayList<Employee> employees;

    Department(String deptName) {
       this.deptName = deptName;
       this.employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.deptName;
    }
    public void addEmployee(Employee a){
        if( employees.isEmpty())
        employees.add(a);
        else
        {
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < employees.size(); ++i ){
               if( employees.get(i).gAge() > a.gAge()  ){
                   employees.add(i, a);
                   break;
               }
            }
        if( i == employees.size() )
            employees.add(a);

        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees(){
        return employees;
    }

}
```